# Web-scrapper functionality in salesforce

Tags: website-integration

I am not sure this question might has many solution but I need your guideline to proceed further.

In salesforce we have integrate the functionlaity like automation testing.

We are providing some data from salesforce, this data is need to search on third party website, after search website will display the different codes, we have to pickup appropriate code. 
after getting this code, pass that code again to other website and search for this code and pickup respective data related to this code.

This functionlaity I want automatic. 
I think we can call it as a webscrapper. but I've no idea.
Is anybody having idea, how we can do implement this in salesforce.

Comment: "web scraper" or "spider" are two common terms. But we're not really a "code-writing" service. What resources have you looked at so far? What code have you written? Where are you stuck? Once you've taken the first step, we'll help you take the next. Please read [ask] for more information.

Comment: @sfdcfox. Thank you. I'm not expecting any code from you. I just need your guideline how to get started at initial level. No idea how to move ahead for this requirement.

Comment: Without knowing more, it's hard to say, but I'd guess you'll need Database.Batchable, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Http, Dom.Document, Dom.XmlNode, and maybe some Visualforce or some way to kick off and monitor the process. This is not a trivial requirement. It'd take me a good few hours to even come up with a working prototype. I've given you a few hints, but you're doing to need to do a fair amount of research. You might be better off just installing a scraper in a VM somewhere and calling it directly.